# When I copy from something on the CLI in TMUX it adds to the buffer instead of overwriing it

Tags: tmux

No sure what I'm missing here. When I copy something using shortcuts or mouse it adds the copied content to what is all ready there.

Eg. I copy 'Applications' and past 'Applications' appears. When I copy 'Desktop' and past it  it will show 'Applications Desktop'.

Relevant tmux.conf and tmux version 3.0a

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
# more settings to make copy-mode more vim-like
unbind [
bind Escape copy-mode
unbind p
bind p paste-buffer
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection

# Buffers to/from Mac clipboard, yay tmux book from pragprog
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste-buffer"
```

Answer (score 0):

My guesses would be 1) since you have not turned `set-clipboard` off, tmux is setting the clipboard with OSC 52 2) you are using Kitty terminal, which has a bug where it appends to the clipboard instead of overwriting it. You should either:

- Turn `set-clipboard` off so that only `pbcopy` is setting the clipboard:

```
set -g set-clipboard off
```

- Do not use `pbcopy` and just use `set-clipboard`, but change to a terminal which handles it correctly.

Comment: I am using kitty. But ```  
# set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /bin/zsh"``` and as you can see I had that commented out. Once I removed the comment it worked as expected.